# The difference between totally (large) cocontinuous functors and small cocontinuous functors

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors, yoneda-lemma, kan-extensions

$\newcommand{\cat}{\mathbf}\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\newcommand{\cSet}{\cat{Set}}$A category $\cat C$ is *total* if the Yoneda embedding $\cat C→[\cat C^{\op},\cSet]$ has a left adjoint. This left adjoint sends $F ∈ [\cat C^\op,\cSet]$ to the coend $∫^x x·F(x)$. This is a strengthening of the notion of cocompleteness, where we require that diagrams indexed by *large* categories, but still controlled by the size of $\cat C$, have a colimit.

Let us call a functor $G : \cat C → \cat D$ *totally cocontinuous* (nonstandard terminology) if it preserves all these coends, meaning that $G(∫^x x·F(x)) = ∫^x G(x)·F(x)$ for all $F ∈ [\cat C^\op,\cSet]$. One can show that $G$ is totally cocontinuous if and only if it has a right adjoint (without condition on $\cat D$), which is $d ↦ ∫^x x·\Hom(G(x),d)$. I think it is the most direct analogue of the posetal case. So "totally cocontinuous functors" are just left adjoints functors, which probably explains why there is not another name for these.

One technically "has to be careful" because I imagine not every *small* cocontinuous functor (only colimits indexed by small categories are preserved) is *totally* cocontinuous. Can someone give me an idea of how bad things can go if we only assume small cocontinuity?

I found an example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21394/112735) (last paragraph), but the reason there is no right adjoint is that the target category is not locally small instead of the functor being small cocontinuous and not totally cocontinuous (the presheaf $\Hom(G(—),d)$ is not valued in sets). Is there an example of small cocontinuous functor $\cat C→\cat D$ with no right adjoint where $\cat C$ and $\cat D$ are locally small, and $\cat C$ is total?

Comment: It's a good question! Another classic example that's not quite good enough has domain the opposite of the category of groups, which is cototal but not total. In *The adjoint functor theorem and the Yoneda embedding* Ulmer claims to know some artificial examples of cocontinuous but not totally cocontinuous functors, but doesn't describe them, and I'm not sure whether they help.

Comment: @KevinArlin Thanks. This example is described on [the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+category#examples). Based on that, I realized there is a very simple answer to my question, but it is posetal, so not as good… Still, it gives an idea of why we need to assume *total* cocontinuity to have a right adjoint. Take the category of ordinals with a top element added. It is total, but the presheaf sending everything to $1$ except the top to $0$ transforms small colimits into limits but is not representable. I would be interested if someone manages to build a non-posetal example.

Comment: Since total categories are complete (and hence Cauchy-complete), by the (More )General Adjoint Functor theorem, a small cocontinuous functor would fail to have a right adjoint if and only if there is an object $Y\in\mathbf D$   failing the solution set condition, i.e. for which there is no set of morphisms $GX_i\to Y\in\mathbf D$ such that every morphism $GX\to Y\in\mathbf D$  factors as $GX\to GX_i\to Y$ for some morphism $X\to X_i\in\mathbf C$. So perhaps you can modify an example of where an adjoint fails to exist due to failing the solution-set condition to get an answer.